# Reading CSV file with different count of column in few row

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am having a CSV file present in ADLS Gen 2 with different column count in few rows. Eg First rows would have 8 columns and second row would have 12 column. When i am trying to create Pyspark dataframe out of this, it creating df based on the first row i.e dataframe with 8 column and ignoring 4 columns of second row.

I have also tried using ADF mapping dataflow but same schema is being created.

I also tried to generate schema as i know what would be the maximum column and their name  but issue in that is it will then ignore rows having 8 column and would only have record having same number of column in schema generated i.e 12

I noticed that its creating header based on first row of file.

Since file is coming from the client so data with least column can come at first row or some where in middle or at last.

I noticed that its creating header based on first row of file s

How to achieve a dataframe having total 12 columns and having Null in last four column of first row.

Answer (score 1):

It's by design, that when you create a dataset, columns will be pulled based on the first-row schema.

Alternatively,

1. Create CSV dataset with `no delimiter`.
2. Using data flow, connect source dataset to source transformation.
3. Use `derived column` transformation to split the row values based on column delimiter using the **split** expression, which returns an array. Store each array element in individual columns.

   Example:

   ```
        column1 = `split(Column_1, ',')[1]
        column2 = `split(Column_1, ',')[2]
        ...
        ...
        column12 = `split(Column_1, ',')[12]
   ```
4. Connect the output of the `derived column` to the sink transformation and map the source columns to sink in sink mappings.

Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619467/azure-data-factory-delimited-text-file-ignoring-imported-schema/72659531#72659531) thread for details.